# PySpark/Jupyter NB : Magic command run failing

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am in JupyterLab trying to run one PySpark notebook from within another but I keep getting the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

The aim here is to have one file that sets up configurations, such as schema definitions and functions, that can be called from a variety of other notebooks that carry out different tasks using those definitions. In the samples below configuration holds the schema definitions etc and dataload is a stripped down version of the one of the notepads carrying out a task.

In this case the **dataload** notepad must run the **configuration** notepad to set up the schemas it is going to use to load data.

**Configuration.ipynb**

```
# Initialization
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('X').getOrCreate()
```

and

```
    # environment setup
    from pyspark.sql import functions
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField
    from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType, DateType

    ex_schema = StructType([
        StructField("graph_sid",StringType()),
.....
        StructField("pack_qty", DoubleType())
    ])
```

**DataLoad.ipynb**

```
# Initialization
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('X').getOrCreate()

%run Configuration.ipynb
```

I get the following error:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~/work/Configuration_FL.ipynb in <module>
      1 # Initialization
----> 2 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
      3 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('X').getOrCreate()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

If I run all the code in one notebook it works well.

I have tried different set-ups in the configuration file, such as removing the #Initialization section, which seem to generate different errors.

At the suggestion of *napoleon_borntoparty* I tried opening both in the same Kernal. This allowed me to access definitions from the dataload in the configuration notepad but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're using the same `kernel` for both of the notebooks. In the respective notebooks, click `Kernel -> Change kernel` and select the same `kernel` for each. Think of the kernels as virtual environments that contain your modules and packages. 
If this doesn't work, please provide more data on the `initialisation` you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply it definitely helped. I have played around with this for a while this evening and I can now see variables defined in the dataload notepad in the configuration notepad but not the other way around. I get the feeling I am missing something obvious. As you requested I have added additional details to the main textbox on the way that I am using these.